# allocation, deallocation and access of dynamic memory in std::vector

Tags: c++, pointers, graph, dynamic-memory-allocation, stdvector

The following Code should create a graph. For that, there are two classes which are edge and graph.
Our Problem is, that the program compiles, but crashes..
In Visual Studio gives the error, that there is a read access violation exception.

We guess, that this comes from the pointer e, beacause this is used wrong. But we don´t know what is actually wrong.

Question: Are the pointers the reason why the program crashes and for the read access violation exception? And what shold be corrected?

We'll appreciate any help and code corrections.

CODE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

class edge {
public:
int s,t;
edge(int s, int t) : s(s), t(t) {}
};

class graph {
public:
int m,n;
vector<edge*> *e;
graph(int n, int m) : n(n), m(m) {
    for (int i=0; i<m; i++) {
        (*e).push_back(new edge(i,-1));
    }
}
~graph() {
    for(int i=m-1;i>=0; i--) {
        delete [] (*e)[i];
    }
}

void make_edge(int i, int s, int t) {
    for(i=0;i<m;i++) {
        assert(((*e)[i]->s!=s)&&((*e)[i]->t!=t));
    }
    assert(s!=t);
    assert(s+1==t);

}
};

int main() {
const int n=4;
const int m=3;
graph g(n,m);
g.make_edge(0,0,1);
g.make_edge(1,1,2);
g.make_edge(2,2,3);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to initialize `vector<edge*> *e;`. Vote to close as typo.

Comment: Why do you have a pointer to a vector and not just a vector? I can imagine no reason the pointer is preferable..

Comment: If you had your warnings on, you would've seen it

Comment: Also don't use `std::vector<edge*>`, use `std::vector<edge>`. This way the elements are removed automatically, no need for manual cleanup.

Answer (score 4):

Your class `graph` is using member `e`, which is a pointer to class of type `std::vector<edge*>`', however this member `e` was not allocated prior to usage in constructor. This is why the crash